# How to make a valid Regular Expression for String.matches() for "image/*" in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Spring Boot application, I am making an API which Accepts value in Request Header of type application/pdf or image/*.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/test, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<?> getSomething( @RequestHeader(name = "Accept") @NotEmpty List<String> 
        acceptTypes)
```

I want to validate whether it contains any of image/* like image/png etc.

```
boolean acceptHeaderValid = false;
for (String acceptType : acceptTypes) {
    if (acceptType.matches("image/*") || acceptType.matches(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)) {
          acceptHeaderValid = true;
          break;
    }
}
```

But when I send image/* in Accept header in Insomnia, acceptType.matches("image/*") evaluates to false. What is the mistake in the Regular Expression? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be very sophisticated, but an easy approach would be to just make use of `String.startsWith`
Literally:

```java
acceptType.startsWith("image/")
```